# Mapping Database entries to Objects in C#

Tags: c#, database

I have table in database which look like this;

```
ID  P_ID    ATTRIBUTE           PARENT_ID   SEQUENCE
----------------------------------------------------
1   1       INDIVIDUAL                              // return the list contains same P_ID with no PARENT_ID, 
2   1       FIRST_NAME          1           1       // element of parent INDIVIDUAL
3   1       SECOND_NAME         1           2
4   1       INDIVIDUAL_ALIAS    1           3   
5   1       ALIAS_NAME          4           1       // element of INDIVIDUAL/INDIVIDUAL_ALIAS
6   1       DOCUMENTS           1           4       
7   1       NATIONAL_IDs        6           1
8   1       ID                  7           1       //element of INDIVIDUAL/DOCUMENTS/NATIONAL_IDs
9   1       Passport            7           2
10  1       SSN                 7           3           
11  2       sdnEntry                                // new parent entry
12  2       firstName           11          1
13  2       lastName            11          2
14  2       aka                 11  
15  2       firstName           14          1
16  2       lastName            14          2
17  1       ENTITY                                  // second list member of P_ID == 1
18  1       FIRST_NAME          17          1
19  1       ENTITY_ALIAS        17  
20  1       ALIAS_NAME          19          1
```

for better understanding tree will be like this;

```
Set up the tree if data fetched with P_ID = 1
                INDIVIDUAL
                    |-FIRST_NAME
                    |-SECOND_NAME
                    |-INDIVIDUAL_ALIAS // list of ALIAS_NAME
                        |-ALIAS_NAME
                    |-DOCUMENTS // list of NATIONAL_IDs
                        |-NATIONAL_IDs // further list of documents
                            |-ID
                            |Passport
                            |SSN // may some other entry contains list here too 

                ENTITY
                    |-FIRST_NAME
                    |-ENTITY_ALIAS
                        |-ALIAS_NAME
```

My Classes for Mapping data; It will be highly appreciated if anyone suggest which does not require more tables as tree grows, as current if I am increasing level of tree, require to create class for that.

```
public class Attribute
    {
        public int ProcessId { get; set; }
        public List<ParentAttribute> ParentNodes { get; set; }        
    }

    public class ParentAttribute
    {        
        public int id { get; set; } 
        public string parentNodeValue { get; set; }
        public List<ChildAttribute> ChildNodeValues { get; set; }
    }

    public class ChildAttribute
    {
        public int? sequence { get; set; }
        public string childNodeValue { get; set; } //can be only string OR List<ChildAttribute>
        //public dynamic childNodeValue { get; set; } //unable to work with dynamic and object
        public int? parentId { get; set; }

    }
    //I was thinking to add table if tree level goes further up, but this is not good approach

        public class GrandChildAttribute
        {
            public int sequence { get; set; }
            public string grandChildNodeValue { get; set; }
            public int parentId { get; set; }
        }

this is how I am trying to map data in my C# code, Which is also not good way, I need  to add another foeeach loop if data needs to be taken from further list.

public static Attribute GetProcessAttributes()
        {
            using (OracleConnection oCon = new OracleConnection(Con))
            {
                Attribute att = new Attribute();

                string query = @"SELECT * from Process where Process_Id = :Process_Id";                
                OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand(query, oCon);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Process_Id", 1);
                oCon.Open();
                OracleDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                dt.Load(rdr);

                if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
                {

                    foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
                    {
                        att.ProcessId = Convert.ToInt32(row["Process_Id"]);

                        att.ParentNodes = new List<ParentAttribute>();
                        var pNodes = (from pRow in dt.AsEnumerable()
                                      where pRow.Field<decimal?>("Parent_Id") == null
                                      select pRow).ToList();

                        foreach (var pItem in pNodes)
                        {
                            ParentAttribute pAtt = new ParentAttribute();
                            pAtt.parentNodeValue = pItem["Attribute"].ToString();
                            pAtt.id = Convert.ToInt32(pItem["ID"]);

                            pAtt.ChildNodeValues = new List<ChildAttribute>();

                            var cNodes = (from cRow in dt.AsEnumerable()
                                          where cRow.Field<decimal?>("Parent_Id") == pAtt.id
                                          select cRow).ToList();


                            foreach (var cItem in cNodes)
                            {
                                int currentId = Convert.ToInt32(cItem["ID"]);
                                var gNodes = (from gRow in dt.AsEnumerable()
                                              where gRow.Field<decimal?>("Parent_Id") == currentId
                                              select gRow).ToList();
                                ChildAttribute cAtt = new ChildAttribute();

                                if (gNodes.Count > 0)
                                {
                                    cAtt.childNodeValue = new List<ChildAttribute>();
                                    cAtt.sequence = Convert.ToInt32(!cItem.IsNull("Sequence"));
                                    cAtt.parentId = Convert.ToInt32(!cItem.IsNull("Parent_Id"));

                                    ChildAttribute gAtt = new ChildAttribute();
                                    //unable to add this list to its parent
                                    foreach (var gItem in gNodes)
                                    {
                                        gAtt.childNodeValue = new ChildAttribute()
                                        {
                                            childNodeValue = cItem["Attribute"].ToString(),
                                            sequence = Convert.ToInt32(!cItem.IsNull("Sequence")),
                                            parentId = Convert.ToInt32(!cItem.IsNull("Parent_Id"))
                                        };


                                        (cAtt.childNodeValue as List<ChildAttribute>).Add(gAtt);
                                    }

                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    cAtt.childNodeValue = cItem["Attribute"].ToString();
                                    cAtt.sequence = Convert.ToInt32(!cItem.IsNull("Sequence"));
                                    cAtt.parentId = Convert.ToInt32(!cItem.IsNull("Parent_Id"));

                                    pAtt.ChildNodeValues.Add(cAtt);
                                }



                            }
                            att.ParentNodes.Add(pAtt);
                        }                               
                    }                   
                }
                return att;
            }

        }
```

Any other suggestion regarding my requirement will also be appreciated. I need to fetch data as showed in tree to my object class to further work out with them. I am also unable to get data of `INDIVIDUAL_ALIAS` to list, because `FIRST_NAME` and `SECOND_NAME` is string type and `INDIVIDUAL_ALIAS` is list type.

Comment: Do a little reading on [Table per Hierarchy](https://www.google.com/search?q=entity+framework+table+per+hierarchy), that is likely what you are wanting to do.

Comment: @Igor So this is with EntityFramework ?

Comment: Yes but the design is portable, you will be able to find more how to's and documentation if that is what you search on. I should have made that more clear in my comment.